# service-activator throws ClassCastException when receiving Rabbit message

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using spring integration with RabbitMQ AMQP and facing strange behavior.

I'm receiving messages over rabbitMQ  from external service but the service activator throws:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.expression.MapAccessor cannot be            cast to org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor

my code is running in EAR file deployed to Jboss.
when I run the same context XML from a unit test the message is received flawlessly.

setting a wiretap logger shows the message  received as expected.

I'll appreciate any suggestions or thoughts that will guide me through this.

I'm using:

1. spring-expression-3.2.4
2. spring-integration-amqp-2.2.4
3. spring-integration-core-2.2.4
4. spring-rabbit-1.1.4

the application-context is :

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="firedJobInboundChannelAdapter"
    channel="firedNotificationChannel" 
    queue-names="firedJob-jboss-Q"      
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" 
    mapped-request-headers="*" />

 <int:channel id="firedNotificationChannel" />          

 <int:json-to-object-transformer 
    input-channel="firedNotificationChannel" 
    output-channel="firedNotificationChannelObject"
    type="com.company.scheduling.JobStringDataMap"/>

<int:channel id="firedNotificationChannelObject" />


<int:service-activator  input-channel="firedNotificationChannelObject" >
     <bean id="firedSchedulerJobReciverBean" class="com.company.notifications.scheduler.gateway.FiredSchedulerJobReciver"/>         
</int:service-activator>
```

The exception is (error reason is in bold):

> **Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.expression.MapAccessor cannot be cast to org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor**
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getPropertyAccessorsToTry(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:330)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:220)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:112)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:107)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:72)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:63)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
>   at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:103)
>   at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
>   at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:227)
>   at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:127)
>   at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
>   ... 37 more

Comment: Do we really need to see that entire stack trace? Could you perhaps only show the highlighted portion? OR at least copy the whole thing into a pastebin, so the post is easier to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like there is older version of **spring-context.jar** in your JBOSS classpath.
It should be of **3.2.4** too. And ensure that all spring jars are the same version and there is no any copies.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was duplicate  spring-expression jars .